# Postgres error when saving model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I have searched couldn't really find anything relevant. would really appreciate if someone can help me

I keep getting this error when saving a model in rails

> PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "addresses_pkey"

I don't have any index `addresses_pkey`.

My guess is somehow the primary key counter is busted but not really sure how to fix it on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is trying to create the same value in the primary key for the addresses table which shouldn't be happening.

As a workaround, you could also try the following commands:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create 
rake db:migrate
```

For Heroku

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
heroku run rake db:setup
```

Comment: These are not really options when you are dealing with prod data. But I solved my problem. I messed up sequence when I imported data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I imported some data which messed up sequence so I reset all my sequence using this rake task

```
 namespace :db do
  desc 'reset sequences for a specific table or all tables'
  task sequence_reset: :environment do
    sql = <<~SQL
      SELECT 'SELECT SETVAL(' ||
             quote_literal(quote_ident(PGT.schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(S.relname)) ||
             ', COALESCE(MAX(' ||quote_ident(C.attname)|| '), 1) ) FROM ' ||
             quote_ident(PGT.schemaname)|| '.'||quote_ident(T.relname)|| ';' as query
      FROM pg_class AS S,
           pg_depend AS D,
           pg_class AS T,
           pg_attribute AS C,
           pg_tables AS PGT
      WHERE S.relkind = 'S'
          AND S.oid = D.objid
          AND D.refobjid = T.oid
          AND D.refobjid = C.attrelid
          AND D.refobjsubid = C.attnum
          AND T.relname = PGT.tablename
      ORDER BY S.relname;
    SQL

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).each do |query|
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query['query'])
    end
  end
end
```